# Z3 solver - Unsatisfiable model values

Tags: z3, solver

Z3 can output the model and we can extract the values when the input is satisfiable.

**Is there a way to obtain values for our model when we want unsatisfiability?** (note: I'm using the c++ API)

Another way to see this question: when z3 proves that the equations return false, can we print a combination that lead to that unsat (`false`) value?

Comment: What is your goal? If it's unsat, it means *all* combinations lead to that unsat. Is "unsat core" what you're after?

Comment: @GManNickG To my understanding, an unsat core will try to provide which conditions are in conflict but, what I'm trying to see is if I can get a model that contains an example (with actual numbers), so let's say we have `s.add( x > 2)` and `s.add(x < 2)` then a possible unsat model would be a model output such as `(define-fun x () Int 0)` which satisfies `x < 2`

Answer (score 2):

If your input is `unsat`, no assignment to inputs will make it true, i.e., all assignments will lead to false. So, you can just pick arbitrary values for your inputs.

From a practical perspective, however, one easy way to achieve what you want is to assert the negation of your original goal and ask for a model of that from the solver. The model that "satisfies" the negation of your goal will make your original goal "false."

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Comment the below line while solving for Unsatisfiable */            
solver.add(constr);

/* This block gets us Unsatisfiable Constraints, Uncomment the below line */
/*
  * BoolExpr negConstr = ctx.mkNot(constr); solver.add(negConstr);
*/
```

So what we are effectively doing is negating the constraint for which we were solving and this will produce us UN-satisfiable contraint values while extracting from Model values as shown below:

```
Status checkResult = solver.check();
if (checkResult == Status.SATISFIABLE) {
  System.out.println("Satisfiable");
                
  // Get the model for the constraints
  Model model = solver.getModel();
                
  // Extract the values for the string variables
  System.out.println("s = " + model.eval(xExpr, false));
  System.out.println("t = " + model.eval(yExpr, false));
}
```